# Vuejs updating field updating all fields

Tags: vue.js

I have 2 formfields Title and Link, when typing a text into Title also link gets the same value.
Something goes wrong with updateValue method, this wil execute twice.

How can i achieve that both fields getting there own values?

App.vue

```
<form-input v-on:input="handleTitle" :label="'title'" :labelvalue="'Titel'" :type="'text'" :placeholder="''" :name="'title'" :value="title" :classname="'form-control'" :id="''"></form-input>
<form-input v-on:input="handleLink" :label="'Link'" :labelvalue="'Link'" :type="'text'" :placeholder="''" :name="'link'" :value="title" :classname="'form-control'" :id="''"></form-input>

data() {
    return {
        title: '',
        link: '',
    }
}
methods: {
    handleTitle: function (evt) {
        this.title = evt.target.value
    },
    handleLink: function (evt) {
        this.link = evt.target.value
    },
```

Template:

```
 <input v-on:input="updateValue($event)" :type="type" :placeholder="placeholder" :name="name" :value="value" :class="classname" :id="id">

export default {
    props: {
        type: String,
        placeholder: String,
        name: String,
        value: String,
        classname: String,
        id: String,
        label: String,
        labelvalue: String
    },
    methods: {
        updateValue: function (evt) {
            console.log(this.$emit('input', evt))
            this.$emit('input', evt)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your prop `:value` have the same variable in both `<form-input :value="title">`

Comment: oeps... thnx! Can you give it as an answer?

Comment: You also don't need to prefix your attributes with `:`. You only use it if you need to bind data to it. So in your example `:label="'title'"` can just be `label="title"`

Comment: Nice @Beau works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your prop `:value` have the same variable in both `<form-input :value="title">` change one to `<form-input :value="link">`